# My colleague sent a meme but i dont really understand the reference

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[image: lotr meme]
i know smeagol and gollum are basically the same person, but what does it mean in this meme?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I've never heard of this before and it doesn't even show up on knowyourmeme.com

I suspect it's not really a popular meme at all.  If I were to interpret it in the context of the image I'd suggest it's taking the premise that Smeagol/Gollum are fairly wretched characters when nothing goes their way - thus implying a "Smeagol/Gollum" day has been very bad for you when nothing positive has happened.

But really, it seems like someone has invented this as a "meme" and it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

Smeagol is a lonely and wretched character, especially when he does not have his precious ring.

Gollum is the sound the person Smeagol/Gollum makes as punctuation. Read **Gollum!!** as a sound expressing woe.

```
 Have you ever had a wretched day, sigh
```